# Intuition for G$_{\delta}$ density

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

There are quite a few questions on MSE about G$_{\delta}$ sets, particularly asking about why $\mathbb{Q}$ is not G$_{\delta}$. However, my question appears to have not been asked.

At a recent seminar on topics in continuum theory, a speaker said "It turns out that these continua are dense in $X$. In fact, they're G$_{\delta}$ dense". I have a lot of intuition for the usual notion of density, i.e. $A\subset X$ is dense in $X$ if $\bar{A} = X$. However, I have no idea what is meant by G$_{\delta}$ density.

I asked my supervisor and after a few minutes of thinking, she just said "well, we know it's dense"!

At present all I know about G$_{\delta}$ sets is the definition, I don't have a feel for what it means. I would be grateful if this could also be touched on, but my primary question is the meaning and intuition for G$_{\delta}$ density. Thank you.

Comment: Can you give the definition of "$G_\delta$ dense"? Those following your tags will know what $G_\delta$ means but probably not $G_\delta$ dense (I certainly do not know this term, nor can I easily google to find it).

Comment: I can't give the definition (and I can't find it anywhere). My first guess is that it just means a set is dense and it's G$_{\delta}$, but the fact that it's G$_{\delta}$ must affect the nature of "how dense it is". (Otherwise there is no point saying that it's G$_{\delta}$ if denseness is the property we're interested in.)

Comment: Other than meaning that they are dense and also $G_{\delta},$ the only alternative I can think of is a set which is dense and which intersects every dense $G_{\delta}$ set.   Can a set have this property and not be $G_{\delta}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speaker just meant the set is dense (in the topology of $X$) and the set is $G_\delta$. Sets that are both dense and $G_\delta$ come up sometimes in analysis. For example, on the space $C[0,1]$ with supremum norm, the set up functions with no points of differentiability contains a dense $G_\delta$ subset of $C[0,1]$.

Comment: I would say that it is also possible that they could have meant that the set *contains* a dense $G_\delta$, i.e. that it is comeagre/residual.

Comment: Either way it seems I need to teach myself more topology to understand these things.